# C# DynamicLinq where clause with Any()

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to run dynamic linq with a string where clause like this:

```
query = db.Customers.Where("Categories.Any(Code == 'Retail')");
```

Customer entity has collection of categories

```
class Customer
{
    public List<Category> Categories {get;set;}
    ...
}

class Category
{
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

Can anyone please tell me is it possible to do something like this?

PS: I need where clause be string. The where clause will be generated at runtime, for this reason I can't use Linq query expression.

I'm using Telerik DataAccess.

Comment: What are the possible variations of the dynamic clause, do you mean the Code is not fixed or the whole condition ? Can you give couple of more different examples ?

Comment: You can use [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173144.aspx) for this. Probably you need some builder to build your string query to Expression tree.

Comment: What is the version of EF you are using?

Comment: I'm using Telerik DataAccess 2015.1.225.1

Comment: There is library for dynamic linq http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible as soon as you follow the [Expression Language](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#expression-language) rules.

For instance, string literals must be enclosed in double quotes:

```
query = db.Customers.Where("Categories.Any(Code == \"Retail\")");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own runtime `Expression`:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> myRuntimeExpression = null;

if(condition1)
{
    myRuntimeExpression = cust => cust.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Code == "Retial"); // or some local variable
}
else if(condition2)
{
    myRuntimeExpression = cust => cust.Categories.Any(cat => cat.Id = someId) == false;
}
else if(condition3)
{

}

var query = DB.Customers.Where(myRuntimeExpression);
```

However, if you need to build more complex queries have a look at [Dynamic Queries in Linq Using Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654267.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be like below?

```
refinedCustomerList = db.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Categories.Any(Code == 'Retail'));
```

The above list will contain all the customers whose category is 'Retail'

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this :

```
query =  db.Customers.Where(x => x.Categories.Where(y => y.Code == "Retail").Any());
```

Comment: I need where clause be string.

Comment: @Daler for what reason?

Comment: Because it's not predefined, clause will be generated on runtime.

Comment: Why is it generated at runtime? if there's options why not just have different quires to be run depending on the options

Comment: @Daler i doubt it would be possible as far as i know, you can only pass strings for expressions but for API functions as part of the string, I never encountered cases like that

Comment: Cause it should work in big project with large number of entities and options.

Answer (score 1):

The [linq extention method were](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) accepted an argument of type `System.Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>`

- In your case a `Func` that recieves a `Customer` as an argument and returns true / false.
  The result of the Where function would be all the `Customers` that the `Func` returned `true` for.

`"Categories.Any(Code == 'Retail')"` is a string, not a `Func`, thus cannot be passed as an argument to the `Where` method.

Perhaps what you are looking for, if you want to keep the query flexible is some thing like:

```
Public Customer[] QueryCustomers(Func<Customer,bool> predicate)
{
    var result =  db.Customers.Where(c=> predicate(c)).ToArray();
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
var retailCustomers =
      QueryCustomers(customer => customer.Categories.Any(Code == 'Retail'))
```

Or any other query you might compose in run/compile time:

```
var customersWithNoCategories =
      QueryCustomers(customer => customer.Categories.Count == 0)
```